# get the lowest value of a double[]

Tags: java, double, overflow

i wrote the following codes

my aim is to get the lowst value of `doble[] absOfSub` but it gives the following exception
at line          `compared= Double.compare(d2, d1);`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

why overflow and how to fix it?

## EDIT

```
  public class TestThe {
static double[] absOfSub = new double[5];
    private static int index=0;

  private static int compare(int currentIdx, int minIdx) {
      if(index < absOfSub.length) {
         if(absOfSub[currentIdx] < absOfSub[minIdx]) {
             compare(currentIdx + 1, currentIdx);
         } else {
             compare(currentIdx + 1, minIdx);
         }
      }
  return minIdx;
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    absOfSub[0]=1000;
    absOfSub[1]=810;
    absOfSub[2]=108;
    absOfSub[3]=130;
    absOfSub[4]=110;
double result;
   int inndex= compare(0,1);
      System.out.println(absOfSub[inndex]);
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though your code can be fixed, it is unnatural to implement `min` by recursion in Java. Why don't you just rework it to a simple iterative solution?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik more explaination? how to make it more simpler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this simple and elegant solution?

```
static double min(double... ds) {
  double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  for (double d : ds) min = Math.min(min, d);
  return min;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(min(-5.2, 0, -10.1, 3));
}
```

Recursive solution (not recommended!):

```
static double minRecur(double... ds) {
  return minRecur(ds, 0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
}
static double minRecur(double[] ds, int i, double runningMin) {
  return (i < 0 || i >= ds.length)? 
    runningMin : minRecur(ds, i + 1, Math.min(runningMin, ds[i]));
}
```

Comment: your solution looks good but the first line should be changed into the value of first index of **double[]** :P

Comment: And what if you call with an empty array? A default value makes this cleaner. In any case, if you never call it with an empty array, your proposed change doesn't bring any difference in behavior.

Comment: but i copy/pasted into my own prog, didnt work unless i did the change ...by the way how will my own question being fixed? just in case to know how to manage to change the index value in each iteration :)

Comment: Watch closely. I first posted my answer with the wrong default value. Check it as it stands now. As for your question, you are not even trying to do iteration, but recursion. In a language with tail-call optimization, your solution would be great. To many FP-loving people's regret, Java is not such a language.

Comment: I expanded my answer to include a proper recursive solution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't change the value of `index` inside your method. So this recursive method call won't stop at all.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually change the index variable, so the recursion will never end. But there is a lot more wrong with this.

An easy generic way to find the minimal value in an array, without using recursion:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    // Math.min returns the lower value of the two arguments given
    min = Math.min( min, array[i] );
}
return min;
```

This could be easily adapted to fit your needs.

Comment: I think you mean array.length here, not array.length()

Comment: Ah yes, I changed it. Also made it a bit more Java friendly.

Answer (score 2):

You never manipulate the value of the `index` variable. You see another reason why people should try to limit the number of static variables they use. Let me try to help you:

```
public class TestThe {
  private static double[] absOfSub = new double[5];
  private static void compare(int currentIdx, int minIdx) {
      if(currentIdx < absOfSub.length) {
         if(absOfSub[currentIdx] < absOfSub[minIdx]) {
             return compare(currentIdx + 1, currentIdx);
         } else {
             return compare(currentIdx + 1, minIdx);
         }
      } else {
         return minIdx;
      }
  } 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      absOfSub[0] = 10;
      absOfSub[1] = 810;
      absOfSub[2] = 108;
      absOfSub[3] = 130;
      absOfSub[4] = 110;
      System.out.println("The minimum value is: " + absOfSub[compare(0, 0)]);
  }
}
```

**EDIT** Some more notes:

- always specify the attribute accessor as private, when this is the intention
- always format your code
- when you write recursion, make sure you always change something for every consequent call and that it gets you closer to the ending condition.
- `double` primitive type itself defines a comparison operator, no need to use `Double.compare` in your case.

Comment: +1 for the more note: Yes it is advised to mention the access specifier as private since most of your code and variable means only to your class. not to outside world :)

Comment: dont you mean **compare(0,1)**?

Comment: You can save one iteration if you call it with `compare(1, 0)` (thus not considering the first element once more), but it will work the suggested way also.

Comment: @lonesome on the other hand you can specify `compare(0, n)` where `n` is random index in  the array you know that exist and the function will still remain returning the correct value. This is because you will iterate all the values in the array either way...

Comment: @lonesome are you sure you took everything from my code? I am sure you didn't. Please take another closer look at my code. I didn't implemented it to spare you coding, I wanted to show you, teach you...

Comment: giving the error as **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5**

Comment: @lonesome you were looking to older version of my post. Change `index < absOfSub.length` to `currentIndex < absOfSub.length`, otherwise you are not following my third note.

Comment: it returned **810** which isnt the min among the array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10464/discussion-between-boris-strandjev-and-lonesome)

Answer (score 0):

Index in each routine is having either 0 or 1 or 2 as the value.